# Admob multiple ad units when I have one activity

Tags: admob, google-ads-api, googleads-mobile-unity

I'm building a game in Unity that uses AdMob ads. In the app I only have one screen (a map with objects). I want to add a rewarded ad to 1) speed up an upgrade 2) unlock boosters. They all are on one map (one activity).
In this case should I use 2 ad units or only a single is ok?
I am aware that I should use one ad unit per activity but how does it apply to my case?

** can google punish me (make some limits) for too many requests if I use more (10+) ad units in one screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case it is recommended to use 2 Ad Units, because you have 2 different rewards.

[Policies for ads that offer rewards](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/7313578?hl=en)

> - Each rewarded inventory ad must be offered individually.

Rewarded Ad opens in a separate activity by itself, this is not considered 2 Ad Units in one activity, this rule is for Banner ads & native ads, but interstitial ads & rewarded ads are shown in a different Activity from AdMob.

> ** can google punish me (make some limits) for too many requests if I use more (10+) ad units in one screen?

**No** (but of course they could always punish you for no reason at all, even if you did not violate any guideline)